# Is there a fix for Revit 2019 plugin to use the latest version of CefSharp?

Tags: cefsharp, revit-api, revit

I'd like to know if there is something new to the issue with Revit 2019 and CefSharp, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the next release will be in 2020. However, check this one out: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-architecture-forum/revit-2020-release-dates-and-notes/m-p/8623656#M231207

Answer (score 0):

I discussed this very question and provided an alternative solution for Revit 2019 (and any other version of Revit, and any other program at all, for that matter) by [using IPC for disentanglement](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/04/set-floor-level-and-use-ipc-for-disentanglement.html).

Using IPC, you can implement the functionality you want (e.g., specific CefSharp access) in a separate process, and make that available to your Revit add-in without conflicting with whatever other stuff Revit itself is doing and using.